# Google map api, как установить множество маркеров?

Tags: google-maps

Подскажите, есть ли удобный инструмент, с помощью которого можно быстро проставить множество маркеров на карте, как на рисунке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или нужно для каждой конкретной координаты вычислять долготу и широту отдельно, на странице https://www.google.com.ua/maps/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта часть отвечает за вставку маркера по координатам на гугл карту, т.е. вам нужен массив координат, по которому вы пройдетесь циклом вставляя на карту маркеры.

```
var markers = [], map;
var image = 'image-url.png';
var $googleMap = $('.googleMap');

var addMarker = function(location, map, image) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
    markers.push(marker);
};

var markersAdd = [{lat: 48.466411, lng: 35.0490800},{lat: 48.466411, lng: 35.0490800}];

map = new google.maps.Map($googleMap[0], {
    center: {lat: 48.4662200, lng: 35.0488985},
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 18
}); // Инициализации карты

for (var index in markersAdd) {
    var location = markersAdd[index];
    if (location.lat && location.lng) {
        addMarker(location, map, image);
    }
}
```

Comment: это то понятно что нужен массив, а как получить этот массив из 1000 маркеров?

Comment: Создавайте этот массив, как вы поставили вопрос так я вам и ответил.

Comment: Я вам оставил вчера свой скайп напишите мне туда, толку будет больше )))

Comment: я спросил, как можно быстро проставить множество маркеров? есть ли для этого удобный инструмент?  По вашему создавать массив из 1000 маркеров это будет быстро и удобно?

Comment: Я же не знаю какие вам маркеры нужны )))) Если у вас есть это список то именно таким образом.

Comment: раз уж спросил здесь, хотелось- бы уже здесь увидеть решение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61100/discussion-between-shnur-and-word).